XHR Failed Error When Searching for Extensions in VSCode
Environment

CPU: M3 pro
OS: macOS Sonoma 14.5
Editor: Visual Studio Code 1.89.1

Issue
I am encountering an issue with Visual Studio Code when searching for extensions. The details of the issue are as follows:

When I search for extensions, an "XHR failed" error occurs.
When I select an extension, I can see the details for about a second before the "XHR failed" error appears.
I can download and install extensions using .vsix files locally without any issues.

Error Log
2024-05-28 23:19:07.368 [info] Started local extension host with pid 29434.
2024-05-28 23:19:09.953 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 11ms
2024-05-28 23:19:14.423 [error] Error: XHR failed
    at y.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:97:2011)
2024-05-28 23:20:21.585 [warning] Settings pattern "GitHub.copilot.manageExtension" doesn't match any settings
2024-05-28 23:20:45.697 [error] Error: XHR failed
    at y.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:97:2011)
2024-05-28 23:20:47.979 [warning] Settings pattern "GitHub.copilot.manageExtension" doesn't match any settings
2024-05-28 23:29:09.451 [error] Error: XHR failed
    at y.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:97:2011)
2024-05-28 23:29:09.631 [error] Error: XHR failed
    at y.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:97:2011)
2024-05-28 23:29:09.649 [error] XHR failed: Error: XHR failed
    at y.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:97:2011)
2024-05-28 23:30:35.335 [warning] Settings pattern "GitHub.copilot.manageExtension" doesn't match any settings

Steps I have tried:

Restarting the OS
Rebooting the router
Using iPhone tethering
Changing VSCode user settings for proxy:

Tried turning Http: Proxy Support off, on, fallback, and override
Unchecked Proxy Strict SSL
Left Http: Proxy field empty


Switching to Google's DNS servers
Clearing all VSCode and brew caches and reinstalling VSCode using the following commands:

rm -rf /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app
rm -fr ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.helper.plist
rm -fr ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.plist
rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode
rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt/
rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/
rm -fr ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.microsoft.VSCode.savedState/
rm -fr ~/.vscode/
rm -fr ~/.vscode*
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/code
rm -rf Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/*VSCode*
brew uninstall --cask visual-studio-code
brew cleanup -s

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue.
Thank you!
